# It is possible to update item without hash key or range key value in dynamoDB PHP?

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

```
Record1: [{
"business_id": 2,
"forms": {
    "f522": {
        "id": "f522",
        "is_deleted": 0,
        "title": "Form 1"
        },
    "f8b6": {
        "id": "f8b6",
        "is_deleted": 0,
        "title": "Form 2" 
       },
    "fw56": {
        "id": "fw56",
        "is_deleted": 0,
        "title": "Form 3" 
      }
}
}]

Record2: [{
"business_id": 3,
"forms": {
    "f788": {
        "id": "f788",
        "is_deleted": 0,
        "title": "Form 11"
    },
    "f6yy": {
        "id": "f6yy",
        "is_deleted": 0,
        "title": "Form 12"
    },
    "f00i": {
        "id": "f00i",
        "is_deleted": 0,
        "title": "Form 13"
    }
}
}]

Record3: [{
"business_id": 4,
"forms": {
    "f839": {
        "id": "f839",
        "is_deleted": 0,
        "title": "Form 21"
    },
    "f1bc": {
        "id": "f1bc",
        "is_deleted": 0,
        "title": "Form 22"
    },
    "f6ac": {
        "id": "f6ac",
        "is_deleted": 0,
        "title": "Form 23"
    }
}
}]
```

I have 3 records stored in dynamoDB table. Hash Key is business_id. forms object is parent object with child objects(id, is_deleted, title). I don't know business_id value. But i have only id value "f6yy". I want update is_deleted to 1 of id(value is f6yy). Please suggest whole query.

Comment: I have 3 records stored in dynamoDB table. Hash Key is business_id. forms object is parent object with child objects(id, is_deleted, title). I don't know business_id value. But i have only id value "f6yy". I want update is_deleted to 1 of id(value is f6yy). Please suggest whole query.

Comment: It is not possible to update an item without hash key and sort key

Comment: Thank you @notionquest for the answer. I have another question for the same above data.

I don't have range key. I have only hask key then it is possible to update item in dynamoDB?

Comment: For a composite primary key, you must provide values for both the partition key and the sort key.

Answer (score 1):

There is no such query because logically AWS cannot identify the entry you want to modify if it is not provided with the key(business_id) for the entry in the table.

Hence you need to either change your schema and design it according to your queries or decompose the table to multiple tables so the database will be something like

```
table 1- business_id  form_id(ex. f6yy etc)
table 2- form_id     form_object(ex. {"is_deleted": 0,"title": "Form 1"})
```

Now the update can be done on table 2 for f6yy.

Answer (score 0):

In order to delete the item from DynamoDB table, both partition and sort keys are required.

> For the primary key, you must provide all of the attributes. For
>   example, with a simple primary key, you only need to provide a value
>   for the partition key. For a composite primary key, you must provide
>   values for both the partition key and the sort key.