# It is possible to update item with only hash key in dynamoDB PHP? I Don't have range key value

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

Record1:

```
[{
    "business_id": 2,
    "user_id" =  5,
    "forms": {
        "f522": {
            "id": "f522",
            "is_deleted": 0,
            "title": "Form 1"
        },
        "f8b6": {
            "id": "f8b6",
            "is_deleted": 0,
            "title": "Form 2"
        },
        "fw56": {
            "id": "fw56",
            "is_deleted": 0,
            "title": "Form 3"
        }
    }
}]
```

Record2:

```
[{
    "business_id": 3,
    "user_id" =  1,
    "forms": {
        "f788": {
            "id": "f788",
            "is_deleted": 0,
            "title": "Form 11"
        },
        "f6yy": {
            "id": "f6yy",
            "is_deleted": 0,
            "title": "Form 12"
        },
        "f00i": {
            "id": "f00i",
            "is_deleted": 0,
            "title": "Form 13"
        }
    }
}]
```

Record3:

```
[{
    "business_id": 4,
    "user_id" =  3,
    "forms": {
        "f839": {
            "id": "f839",
            "is_deleted": 0,
            "title": "Form 21"
        },
        "f1bc": {
            "id": "f1bc",
            "is_deleted": 0,
            "title": "Form 22"
        },
        "f6ac": {
            "id": "f6ac",
            "is_deleted": 0,
            "title": "Form 23"
        }
    }
}]
```

I have 3 records stored in dynamo-db table. Hash Key is business_id and range key is user_id. forms object is parent object with child objects(id, is_deleted, title). I don't know user_id value. But I have only business_id value "2"(Which is unique. not repeated in other record business_id). I want update record 2 is_deleted value to 1 of id(value is f6yy). If possible, Please suggest query.

Comment: Answered as part of this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42992783/it-is-possible-to-update-item-without-hash-key-or-range-key-value-in-dynamodb-ph

Comment: This is an exact duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42992783/it-is-possible-to-update-item-without-hash-key-or-range-key-value-in-dynamodb-ph , and I can't vote to close this as a duplicate because the other has not been answered yet.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because you have asked an exact duplicate here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42992783/it-is-possible-to-update-item-without-hash-key-or-range-key-value-in-dynamodb-ph.  Accept an answer there if it answers your question (note: this cannot be closed as duplicate as it has no accepted answer)

Answer (score 0):

No it is not possible.

But as an alternate route you can update whole value by replacing with new Value.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, AWS sdk for dynamodb requires both key values for the update operation, hence both keys are necessary because the entry can be identified only using both the keys.

Secondly: You mentioned

> (Which is unique. not repeated in other record business_id)

If the mapping for user_id and business_id is such that no 2 users can have the same business_id then you may just use business_id as primary key and not use the user_id as a sort/range key (as it is optional to have a range key). The user_id field will still be there but it will not be a range key anymore.

If that is not the case then what u can do is again use only one key [the primary key (business_id) mentioned above] and store the user_id along with the forms object. I am assuming here that forms object is related to a user_id with a business_id.

The new schema will look something like this

```
{    "Record1": [
           { 
              "business_id": 2,
              "forms": 
                 [ 
                   {
                  "user_id" : 5,
                  "f522": { "id": "f522", "is_deleted": 0, "title": "Form 1" }, 
                  "f8b6": { "id": "f8b6", "is_deleted": 0, "title": "Form 2" },
                   "fw56": { "id": "fw56", "is_deleted": 0, "title": "Form 3" } 
                    } 
                 ]
            }
]
}
```

The update operations now becomes non-trivial ,

1. so you will first have to get the entry.
2. update it yourself by iteration and making changes.
3. then use the update operation or a simple putItem with the new object.